# How to include oasis.js from Bower in a webpack build?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack to build my project and I'm having trouble getting it to include oasis.js, specifically https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tildeio/oasis.js/4c657d15a89c532382d2d174783f5c3660111765/dist/oasis.js as pulled in by Bower since there isn't an npm module available for it.

My webpack configuration looks like:

```
'use strict';

const BowerWebpackPlugin = require('bower-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: 'www',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
          { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
          { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new BowerWebpackPlugin({ excludes: [/oasis\.amd\.js$/] }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

and my `./app/index.js` which pulls in Oasis looks like:

```
'use strict';

var oasis = require('oasis.js');
```

When I run `webpack -d`, I get error a series of error messages like:

```
ERROR in ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'oasis/xhr' in /Users/jeffreycharles/projects/dev-container/bower_components/oasis.js/dist
 @ ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js 2983:0-3092:4 3680:0-3780:4

ERROR in ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'oasis/connect' in /Users/jeffreycharles/projects/dev-container/bower_components/oasis.js/dist
 @ ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js 2983:0-3092:4 3093:0-3189:4

ERROR in ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'oasis/logger' in /Users/jeffreycharles/projects/dev-container/bower_components/oasis.js/dist
 @ ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js 2983:0-3092:4 3093:0-3189:4 3217:0-3404:4 3453:0-3679:4 3680:0-3780:4

ERROR in ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'oasis/version' in /Users/jeffreycharles/projects/dev-container/bower_components/oasis.js/dist
 @ ./bower_components/oasis.js/dist/oasis.js 2983:0-3092:4
```

which I find odd since I can see `define("oasis/xhr",` on line 4961 in the oasis file and the other modules that webpack is saying it can't resolve are all in that same file I linked to.

I've also tried setting `noParse` and using the script-loader to load Oasis but then it complains about `RSVP` not being defined. This isn't an issue when I load Oasis using a script tag in my HTML (in fact it all works properly when I do that).

How do I get Webpack to build and include Oasis.js in my project?